# How to find a second/third occurrence in a string in Snowflake/SQL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to recreate the `FINDNTH` function from Tableau into Snowflake/SQL. To use for this formula: `lower(ifnull(left([SKU],(FINDNTH([SKU],"_",2)-1)),[SKU]))`

https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_string.htm
`FINDNTH(string, substring, occurrence)`

The goal is to find the second occurrence of a character, then return everything left of it.

Field: CGM415_Black_3XL

Desired Result: CGM415_Black

I've tried using Position and Charaindex

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/position.html
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/charindex.html

```sql
    Select

    position('_',sku) a,
    position('_',sku,a) b,
    position('_',sku,position('_',sku)) c,
    CHARINDEX('_',sku) d,
    CHARINDEX('_',sku,d) e,
    CHARINDEX('_',sku,CHARINDEX('_',sku)) f,

    sku from DATABASE;
```

All of these columns (a-f) are showing 7 instead of 13 (if CGM415_Black_3XL was the value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following SQL will give you the result

```
substring(sku,1,regexp_instr(sku,'_',1,2)-1)
```

regexp_instr(sku,'-',1,2) will give you the position of 2nd `_`

Comment: Yes! Perfect!  Thanks so much.